# Double.PositiveInfinity in c# returns ∞; is there a method to display "Infinity"?

Tags: c#

In .Net 4, 
Double.PositiveInfinity returns ∞

Is there a method to display "Infinity"

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("PositiveInfinity {0}.", (Double.PositiveInfinity));
    }
}
```

expected is `PositiveInfinity Infinity.`, but the actual output is `PositiveInfinity ∞.`

Comment: Just use a conditional statement like `double x = double.PositiveInfinity; Console.WriteLine("PositiveInfinity {0}.", Double.PositiveInfinity == x ? "Infinity": x.ToString());`...

Comment: @Chayim or `double.IsPositiveInfinity(x) ? ...`

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to know if there is a inbuilt method rather than hardcoding the value. because it used to display "infinity" for versions before .net 4

Answer (score 8):

This can be done by configuring the Current Thread culture. You can set your positive and negative infinity symbols there.
Something like this:

```
var ci = (CultureInfo)Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone();
ci.NumberFormat.NegativeInfinitySymbol = "-Infinity";
ci.NumberFormat.PositiveInfinitySymbol = "+Infinity";                
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;

Console.WriteLine("PositiveInfinity {0}.", (Double.PositiveInfinity));
```

Hope this helps!